# Getting Columns in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

How can I add column headers on top of my uicollectionview for each column?

I've been trying all sorts of things for days and had horrible luck :(
I'm just using a regular uicollectionview and have 20 or so items in it.
I don't need the header to stay floating or anything sophisticated, just need a single label of text above the first row in each column.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. You need to set the `headerReferenceSize` property to something higher than `(0, 0)`. (Or you can implement `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` if the header sizes differ.)

Then just provide your header view in `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`. Your view should be a `UICollectionReusableView`. These work similarly to cells in terms of reusability.

Comment: Can a header take a datasource or something? How do you get N headers to appear for N columns? I hooked into the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind, checked that it's header, and was able to access my subclassed header and change it's text (I have one label in there now). But how do I get N labels in there (for each column)?

Comment: Just make more labels and add them. You can make whatever view you want. Your view controller has access to all of the data.

Comment: how do you ensure the labels are perfectly lined up above the columns? I want to make column headers. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is to create a UIScrollView above the UICollectionView.Add UILabels for each column in the UIScrollView and keep the scrolling synchronized via the UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Both the UIScrollView and UICollectionView will take a UIScrollViewDelegate delegate object.

Comment: I'm sorry you lost me - could you elaborate?